# Como carregar um RecycleView com uma lista?

Tags: android, json, lista

Tenho uma Lista carregado com um JSON de uma consulta com vários registros e várias colunas:

```
List<Videos> lstVideos = new ArrayList<Videos>();
```

Até ai tudo bem. O que eu preciso é carregar um `RecycleView` com essa lista.
Nesse `RecycleView` vai ter uma configuração de *layout* semelhante a esta:

```
Imagem        Titulo do Video

              Descrição


Imagem        Titulo do Video

              Descrição


Imagem        Titulo do Video

              Descrição
```

Como posso fazer isso ?

Podem me dar algum exemplo de código, tutorial, vídeo, seja o que for que me permita realizar algo do tipo? Muito obrigado por toda a ajuda.

Comment: [Documentação do Android](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

Answer (score 1):

Cara, consulte a documentação oficial do android, segue o link:

https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Utilize o google e procure por algum tutorial, tente ajustar o layout conforme a sua necessidade.

Comment: Obrigado, mas isso não ajudou muito

Comment: @user3267188, pra mim esse link da todas as informações necessárias para começar a fazer essa lista, bastando adaptar ao seu "datasource". Eu apenas recomendaria ao marcos, colocar informações pertinentes do link, pois o mesmo pode se tornar inválido (apesar de ser do google, o endereço pode mudar).